# How to add a custom time picker in a Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, timepicker, timespan

I have implemented time input as a length of time in my application using a textbox and parsing the string to a TimeSpan object.

```
//Assign text box string value to a time span variable.
TimeSpan workTm = TimeSpan.ParseExact(wrkString, @"hh\ \:\ mm\ \:\ ss\ \:\ fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I'm wondering how I can add a time picker control like the below image to the application. I don't see any available control in the toolbox.

Is the any custom control that I could use and how is it implemented?

[image: time picker win phone 8.1 app]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're making a Silverlight Windows Phone 8.1 app, you need to use the TimePicker control from Silverlight Windows Phone toolkit.

Read more about TimePicker and DatePicker controls from Silverlight Windows Phone toolkit [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization).

If you're making a WinRT Windows Phone 8.1 app, there's a TimePicker control included in the SDK. (yaay!)

Comes down to using it like this: (Silverlight)

```
<toolkit:TimePicker Value="{Binding Date}” />
```

or: (WinRT)

```
<TimePicker Time="{Binding Time}"/>
```

More info about migrating from one to another which includes certain subtle differences can be found [on Shawn's blog](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/05/16/Migrating-from-the-Windows-Phone-Toolkit-TimePicker-to-the-new-XAML-TimePicker.aspx).

Comment: I don't see any TimePicker control in my toolbox in VS, any idea how I add it to my xaml? I'm developing for Win Phone 8.1

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no control like shown in the OP's image that does TimeSpan; at least not for 8.1 universal.